# Access point with usb ports

Tags: wireless-access-point

How can you connect a printer and a hdd external disk to one access point usb port

is there an alternative to access point?

I want to connect the printer and external hdd to my laptop using a wireless connection for that I have bought tp link wn725n and attached it to my laptop

Maybe use usb hub with the AP usb port?

please suggest access point or solution

Comment: I don't think what you want is even possible. You are likely going to need a NAS or a network print server.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to consider based on your exposition: hardware and software.

AP Hardware: since you have one USB port only you need to use a USB hub in order to increase the number of available ports.
AP Software: the AP should be able to manage both devices, the printer and the external HD.

My recommendation is to confirm that your AP can manage both devices alone that is, without the USB hub. You would need to connect the printer and confirm the AP can manage it and also that your laptop can connect and print to it. Then the same thing with the external HD that is, connect the HD alone, confirm it can be managed by the AP and then confirm it can be accessed by your laptop.

Once the above gets confirmed, go ahead and install the USB hub. Start connecting one device at the time and confirm its accessibility from your laptop.

I had this exact same configuration working problem free -but slow, on a old Asus AP featured with one USB port only.

Comment: do you recommend any such ap?

Comment: Today, if I would set up the same configuration at home again -as it is your case, I would buy something like the TP-Link Archer C9. It is a router but you can use it as an AP by not exploiting its router capabilities that is, not connecting anything to the WAN port. Why I would buy this one? Because it has a dual-core 1GHz processor and it supports 802.11AC for a reasonable price. The configuration you want to build requires a lot of CPU muscle because of the HD. The Archer C9 features sharing media via the USB port and a print server.